# How to add MACs and KEX algorithms in /etc/ssh/sshd_config on Ubuntu 18.04 on GCP

Tags: linux, ubuntu, google-cloud-platform, ssh

I added following MACs to /etc/ssh/sshd_config of Ubuntu 18.04 compute instance on GCP. But after updating the file ssh is not restarting and journalctl -xe shows /etc/ssh/sshd_config line 130: Bad SSH2 mac spec.

```
MACs hmac-sha1-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-512-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-256,umac-128@openssh.com
```

I see following error when I try to restart ssh:

```
$ sudo systemctl restart ssh
Job for ssh.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status ssh.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

$ journalctl -xe
-- 
-- Unit ssh.service has begun starting up.
Aug 02 11:37:17 ubuntu1804 sshd[23779]: /etc/ssh/sshd_config line 130: Bad SSH2 mac spec 'hmac-sha1-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-512-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@open
Aug 02 11:37:17 ubuntu1804 systemd[1]: ssh.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=255
Aug 02 11:37:17 ubuntu1804 systemd[1]: ssh.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug 02 11:37:17 ubuntu1804 systemd[1]: Failed to start OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
-- Subject: Unit ssh.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit ssh.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is RESULT.
Aug 02 11:37:17 ubuntu1804 systemd[1]: ssh.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Aug 02 11:37:17 ubuntu1804 systemd[1]: ssh.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
-- Subject: Automatic restarting of a unit has been scheduled
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Automatic restarting of the unit ssh.service has been scheduled, as the result for
-- the configured Restart= setting for the unit.
Aug 02 11:37:17 ubuntu1804 systemd[1]: Stopped OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
-- Subject: Unit ssh.service has finished shutting down
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit ssh.service has finished shutting down.
Aug 02 11:37:17 ubuntu1804 systemd[1]: ssh.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Aug 02 11:37:17 ubuntu1804 systemd[1]: ssh.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug 02 11:37:17 ubuntu1804 systemd[1]: Failed to start OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
-- Subject: Unit ssh.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit ssh.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is RESULT.
```

Following is the error received when I try to connect after logoff from the existing ssh session.

```
ubuntu1804> gcloud compute ssh ubuntu1804 --zone us-east1-b
ssh: connect to host 35.237.57.183 port 22: Connection refused
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.ssh) [/usr/bin/ssh] exited with return code [255].
```

I did not find a single clue about this in google cloud documentation. I can fix the server but I would like to know what is the right way to add such configuration in sshd_config on a Ubuntu linux on GCP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verify acceptable values for MACs with `ssh -Q mac`. I'd assume `hmac-sha1-512-etm@openssh.com` and `hmac-sha1-512-etm@openssh.com` won't be there.